# Laravel Livewire repeating the last query

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have started learning Laravel Livewire and I am trying to make sections where I can add new form groups dynamically. For example, I want to add some descriptions to my product and in one row I can enter this data: name, description, unit, quantity, etc...

After that, I want to make a button where I can click and add one more row with all these inputs but empty.

**For now, I have used this blog to make this**: https://blog.nterms.com/2021/01/31/edit-items-inhas-many-relationship-with-laravel-livewire.html

Right now, I have a bug where livewire is repeating its last action. For example, if I want to update my data and I remove one field and update another one. On the next request, livewire will try to delete that data again, even though it is already deleted.

Here are some images:

[image]

Then I will add a new row with empty fields:

[image]

The data has been updated and now I will remove one field:

[image]

And send the request again without any changes (so it should do nothing because nothing is changed, but I will get an error that I am trying to delete something):

[image]

Also, sometimes it just randomly duplicates the data. Is there any better way to make this?

**EDIT NO.1**

I was suggested to add the wire:key and this is the result:

I have implemented it like this:

```
@foreach($this->activeUrls as $key => $url)
                        <div wire:key="{{ $key }}" class="form-group">
                            <input wire:model="urls.{{$key}}.url" type="text" value name="url" placeholder="{{ __('Url') }}" class="form-control">
                            <i  wire:click="removeUrl({{$key}})" class="cil-backspace delete-score-row"></i>
                        </div>
                        @error('urls.'.$key.'.url')
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    @endforeach
```

And now when I went to update, instead of 1 field updated and one field added I got this:

[image]

So, one field was updated, one was added, and later on, the added field should have been updated, instead, it stayed as it was and the application just added a new entry with "update data".

Comment: It would help a ton if you actually shared the code you are having issues with

Comment: Hi @Qirel In that blog that I have shared up there is literally all I have used word to word :D If that still does not help I can share some snippets, but yeah that is it pretty much :D just different data for different fields.

Comment: Ensure that your `@foreach` loops have a [`wire:key`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures) attribute as not having one can often cause weird issues. The tutorial you've referenced doesn't appear to make use of them.

Comment: @Peppermintology hello :) Thanks for the comment... So, I have tried adding a key to one of the sections. Check out the result in the question I will update it now.